# Best way to deploy Outlook Add-in to Active Directory users

Tags: deployment, active-directory, outlook, outlook-addin, exchange-server-2010

I recently implemented an Outlook plugin for my enterprise and now I want to deploy it to all of the users on the enterprise. Is there a way to deploy the add-in installer to all of the users on the Active Directory, maybe using Outlook Exchange?

I checked [this](http://documentation.commvault.com/hds/v10/article?p=products/fs_archive_exchange/outlook_addin/deployment.htm) page, and looks like the guys at commvault nailed that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't deploy add-ins via email with Exchange, if that's what you are hoping for.  If your add-in is packaged in a Windows Installer setup file, then you can use traditional Windows Desktop Application deployment methods to distribute your add-in.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks you for your reply. Can you edit your answer to include at least one deployment method to distribute the add-in. Thank you...

Comment: I'm not an expert on enterprise desktop management, sorry. I have no idea what the cool kids in IT are doing these days for deployment - I'm just a developer LOL.  But you might want to look at System Center or WSUS and the like.

Comment: OK, thank you Eric...I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Beware of loading times depending on where and how you install the Addin ([link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsto/2010/11/30/performance-improvements-coming-soon-to-a-service-pack-near-you-stephen-peters/))If you are deploy to the GAC you will need a strongly named assembly (and probably all your references need to be strongly named to)